# Show Outlook Advanced Find dialog from .NET

Tags: vsto, outlook-object-model

When using Outlook 2007 or 2010 you can bring up the Advanced Find dialog by pressing Crtl+Shift+F.

I have performed advanced queries against Outlook contact items and calendar items, but would like to show Outlook's native dialog box for users to perform more advanced searches instead of trying to recreate that dialog box within my app.

I've searched, but have been unable to find details on how to show that dialog box from within a .NET application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why I didn't get the Tumbleweed badge for this question, but I got the answer over on the MSDN forums.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/fe1b7a52-18a3-47d2-a1eb-c22f5c57d454

The Advanced Find dialog is not exposed in Outlook's object model and therefore cannot be called from a .NET app.

So, I'm working on re-creating the dialog box in WPF.